# Run Zend Framework with Apache 2.2

Tags: zend-framework, apache2

I have a project written with zend framework. I was using xampp for my webserver which uses apache 2.2. I decided to use apache 2.2 instead of xampp. I installed apache 2.2 and copied my project into htdocs folder of apache like I did with xampp. But when I enter my project URL into the browser, it doesn't show my index.php and instead, it shows the contents of my file. any idea how to fix this !?
thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll also need to install PHP and enable the PHP module for Apache. Here's the instructions:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.manual.php

AND

http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php

Though personally I like to use WAMPserver - it's super easy to install:

http://www.wampserver.com/en/index.php

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I didn't know php is the problem. thanx.